# how to create a cron expression that fires only once

Tags: cron, cronexpression

By my logic, such a cron expression would be:

```
0 0 0 1 1 ? 2016
```

which should execute only once at Januray 1, 2016 at 12:00 AM, but [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) says such a cron expression is invalid. Is it posible to make cron expression that execute only once at some date in the future?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: `at` is `cron`'s nephew: it executes a command only once.