# PHP CRON expression to execute only once

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

What is the best way to define the cron definition to execute only once and non-recurring job (not to repeat next time)

Say for example to execute only once at Nov 23, 2021, 11:11 AM

I am not sure how to define year in [cron expression generator](https://crontab.guru/)

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416343/how-to-create-a-cron-expression-that-fires-only-once). But anyway no answer for it.

Was using this [PHP Cron expression package](https://github.com/dragonmantank/cron-expression)

Comment: The other question has no answers because if it only executed once, it's not a cronjob. Use `at` instead.

Comment: @DanielW.what do you mean by 'at'?

Comment: `at` is a unix command that does exactly what you want: Run a script once at the given time.

Answer (score 1):

This PHP Cron expression package implementation doesn't support one time running job as YEAR is not a standard field, a cron normally is something you want to schedule and run over-and-over based on a schedule.

May be you have to look for other package which supports one time job feature, but its not possible with this package.

You can use an [expression like 30 12 08 01 *](https://crontab.guru/#30_12_08_01_*), which translates to 12:30 Jan 08 on any day of the week. This will validate for that one day and time, and you would then need to remove the cron entry from wherever you store it.